# JSON Curl with variable causing redirect to defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl, cgi

I am working on integrating The Movie Database.com's API into my site, using a PHP, Curl, and JSON. The following demo code is simply grabbing a sample JSON object and outputting it on the page:

```
$theFields = "?api_key=8746ac61dc4ad34018d62201f3a8a687&query=ferris";
$json_url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie' + $theFields;
// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

echo $result;
```

However, when this code is executed within my WordPress installation, it causes my site to redirect to a defaultwebpage.cgi. If I cut and paste the  contents of $theFields onto the end of the contents of $json_url, it works perfectly with no redirect. Anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiny, but sneaky typo: you've mixed up JavaScript and PHP concatenation operators. Replace `+` with `.` on the second line and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is why Stack Overflow exists - nothing like a second pair of eyes when coding!